# Where are temporary shell variables stored in a shell session?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal, filesystems

Using bash from the terminal, I can declare temporary variables like

```
x = 5
```

and use them like

```
$x
```

Declarations such as these are only valid within the window in which they were declared. If I open a new terminal window, i cannot use $x. I know that if I want to do this I need to add to the .bash_profile file.

But my question is, where in the filesystem are the single-window-only variables stored? Is there a temporary file containing these declarations that is only accessible by the parent process and is deleted when the window is closed? Or is it stored in kernel space somewhere and only referenced by the parent process? Is there any way to see all current temporary variable declarations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are kept in memory in the shell process. You can list them with `set` (output also includes exported variables and functions).